# Running python3 programs on osx Lion

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-lion

I can use python 3 in terminal fine, but I don't know how to make it so terminal will run a program that I have written in python 3.

What do i have to do to associate the .py file extension with python3.2.3 for terminal and not python2.7.1

I am using textwrangler as my text editor, but will happily use any editor if it will run, though I don't think this is my problem as idle doesn't work either and it doesn't have line numbers in it either.

Kind regards

Rob

Answer (score 5):

Add a `python3` hashbang to the beginning of your scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# do stuff
```

Then, you can make your script executable and run it:

```
chmod +x script.py
./script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been struggling somewhat as all the resources I have been looking at are for python3.

Comment: Ok, still struggling, I had this working on Snow Leopard, and I wrote about 50 programs in python as I was learning, now none of them work, I get this kind of error with every single one.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robertkinsey/Documents/Programming/python/Hangman.py", line 164, in <module>
    guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

I am assuming that I have still not successfully got amy mac to run a python3 program. 

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please bear with me, I am trying to follow the rules of the forum, but I can't think quite that fast. I will post my error message in the following post.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "/Users/robertkinsey/Documents/Programming/python<br/>/Hangman.py", line 164, in <module><br/>
    guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")<br/>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module><br/>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined<br/>

Comment: @user1779657 You should be posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

try  `python3 yourprogram.py` in your terminal.

or by adding this line on the top of our programs, this is the path to your interpreter:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.2
```